Issues with Event Handlers D3.js Update Function
I’m experiencing an issue where the mouseover event isn’t working after integrating the update function into my D3.js code. It seems the event listeners are not being recognized or triggered as expected. Could you help me troubleshoot this problem?
Thanks!
function onMouseOver(event, d){
    d3.select(this)
        .attr('class', 'tooltip')
        .transition()
        .duration(200);
    
    const g = d3.select(this.parentNode);

    g.append('text')
        .attr('class', 'val')
        .attr('x', () => x(d.event_name))
        .attr('y', () => y(d.total_event/2))
        .text(() => [d.total_event]);
};

function onMouseOut(d, i){
    d3.select(this).attr('class', 'bar');
    d3.select(this)
        .transition()   
        .duration(400)
    d3.selectAll('.val')
        .remove()
}


function update(dataBar) {

    x.domain(dataBar.map(d => d.event_name))
    xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .selectAll("text")
      .attr("class", "axis-label")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)")
      .style("text-anchor", "end");

    
    y.domain([0, d3.max(dataBar, d => d.total_event)])
        .nice()
    yAxis.transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(10));

    const u = svgBar.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(dataBar)

    u.enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .merge(u)
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
        .attr("x", d => x(d.event_name))
        .attr("y", d => y(d.total_event))
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("height", d => heightBar - y(d.total_event))
        .on("mouseover", onMouseOver)
        .on("mouseout", onMouseOut);


    u.exit().remove()
    
}

The mouseover event works fine without the update function. However, once I add the update function, the mouseover event stops working. I tried incorporating my onMouseOver and onMouseOut functions directly within the update function, but it didn’t resolve the issue. I also attempted to place the event handlers directly in the .on method, but that didn’t work either. My console shows an error indicating that mouseover is not recognized.
Thanks!

I believe this is because you are setting the handlers on the transition (.transition() changes the chained variable to the transition and not the selection).  Switch it to:
u.enter().append("rect")
.attr("class", "bar")
.merge(u)
.on("mouseover", onMouseOver)
.on("mouseout", onMouseOut)
.transition()
.duration(1000)
    .attr("x", d => x(d.event_name))
    .attr("y", d => y(d.total_event))
    .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
    .attr("height", d => heightBar - y(d.total_event));

